# How do I escape % from python mysql query

Tags: python, mysql

How do I escape the % from a mysql query in python.

For example

```
query = """SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_time,'%Y-%m') AS dd
FROM some_table
WHERE some_col = %s
AND other_col = %s;"""

cur.execute(query, (pram1, pram2))
```

gives me a "ValueError: unsupported format character 'Y'" exception.

How do I get mysqldb to ignore the %? Can't see this in any of the docs.

Comment: +1 SO just surprises me. I come here thinking man this is going to be a hard one to phrase! But no, it's already been asked and answered!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Literal escaping is recommended by the [docs](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes):

> Note that any literal percent signs in the query string passed to `execute()` must be escaped, i.e. `%%`.