# Trouble escaping mysql statement in python

Tags: python, mysql

How would I escape the % in the following:

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT MIN(id) FROM title WHERE provider=%s 
                  AND vendor_id LIKE "%s%"''', (provider, vendor_id_stem))
```

Comment: You might look at this version of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037581/how-do-i-escape-from-python-mysql-query?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT MIN(id) FROM title WHERE provider=%s"
               "AND vendor_id LIKE '%s%%'", (provider, vendor_id_stem))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a python variable:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT MIN(id) FROM title WHERE provider=%s AND 
                vendor_id LIKE %s", (provider, vendor_id_stem + '%'))
```