# Python character formatting with mySQL raw db query giving me problems

Tags: python, mysql, sql, format

I'm having a problem with trying to install a search function on my web application. The problem is with the following code. I've tried the following two queries but python gives me an error that I will list below:

```
def searchBox(user_id, searchparams):

try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    if cursor:
        sql = "SELECT * FROM db_email WHERE user_id = %d AND deleted = 0 AND subject LIKE '%%%s%%';"
        cursor.execute(sql % (user_id, searchparams)
```

I have also tried:

```
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    if cursor:
        sql = "SELECT * FROM db_email WHERE user_id = %d AND deleted = 0 AND subject LIKE " + "'%" + searchparams + "%';"
        cursor.execute(sql % (user_id))
```

Both return this error for me:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

This is the only raw queries that I have had any trouble with and it's related to the way I need to call LIKE. I could write a stored procedure instead to bypass python but I feel like I'm doing something dumb and overlooking an issue. Any help would be appreciated

---

Thank you. I think a part of the problem is with my LIKE query I need my searchparams to be enclosed with percentage signs and the below answer doesn't work like so -

```
subject LIKE '%somestringimlookingfor%'
```

with the code above it seems to come out to 'test'%''. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don not use string interpolation for SQL queries, it's completely unsafe.

Instead, use query parameters:

```
sql = """SELECT 
             * 
         FROM 
             db_email 
         WHERE
             user_id = %s AND 
             deleted = 0 AND 
             subject LIKE '%%%s%%'"""
cursor.execute(sql, (user_id, searchparams))
```

Percentage sign should be escaped with `%`.

UPD:

Slightly different option:

```
sql = """SELECT 
             * 
         FROM 
             db_email 
         WHERE
             user_id = %s AND 
             deleted = 0 AND 
             subject LIKE %s"""
cursor.execute(sql, (user_id, "%" + searchparams + "%"))
```

See also:

- [Python MySQL Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables)
- [How do I escape % from python mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037581/how-do-i-escape-from-python-mysql-query)

Comment: Thank you.

I think a part of the problem is with my LIKE query I need my searchparams to be enclosed with percentage signs like so -

    subject LIKE '%somestringimlookingfor%'

with the code above it seems to come out to 'test'%''. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dalbrecht please see `UPD` section in the answer. Let me know if it works for you.