# Python MySQL parameterized query conflicts with % wildcard in LIKE statement

Tags: python, mysql

My query on execution of this fails:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM products WHERE rating > %s AND category like 'Automation %'", (3));
```

Because it gets confused about the percentage usage for two different reasons -- as a LIKE wildcard and as a parameter on python MySQL db execution.

If I run this query like this, it works:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM products WHERE rating > 3 AND category like 'Automation %'");
```

If I run the query as below, it again works:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM products WHERE rating > %s AND category = 'Automation '", (3));
```

But that's not a solution. I want to use both the wildcard and the parameter.

I found a workaround, which is to pass in my constant wildcard as a variable:

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM products WHERE rating > %s AND category like %s", (3, 'Automation %'));
```

This works but I need a more elegant solution. I don't want to pass constants as variables. My SQL statement could have a lot of LIKE statements in a big query.

Comment: what about doubling the %?  e.g. `cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM products WHERE rating > 3 AND category like 'Automation %%'");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably escape it using an extra `%`:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM products WHERE rating > %s AND category like 'Automation %%'", (3));
```

This apparently [works for MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3037581/748858) and I would expect it to work for python-mysql as well. . .

Answer (score -3):

Try to use format. If you have a string, against use %s you can use {}.

```
sql = "SELECT name FROM products WHERE rating > {0} AND category like 'Automation %'"
slq = sql.format(3)
cursor.execute(sql);
```

This is much better and compliance to new versions of python. And, plus, you can get annoyed of % in your query.

Comment: This is also subject to sql injection . . .