# python - MySQLdb Like operator with wildcard

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am having problems executing a query with a wildcard in it with MySQLdb in python.

My code

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%s%'"
with con:
    cur.execute(sql, (name,))
```

The complicated thing about this is the % after the string %s. Based on the documentation, if there's no wildcard operator %, I could just do `LIKE %s` but I don't know how to proceed from there for my problem.

I found this question on stack [Python MySQL parameterized query conflicts with % wildcard in LIKE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536676/python-mysql-parameterized-query-conflicts-with-wildcard-in-like-statement) which is similar to my question but doesn't take a dynamic argument. I tried escaping the wildcard operator like in the link above, but I still get a SQL syntax error.

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any "dynamic argument" here

Comment: the % character is a special character and has to be escaped as %%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the wildcard into the parameter.

```
param = '{}%'.format(name)
sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE name LIKE %s"
with con:
    cur.execute(sql, (param,))
```

Note, you shouldn't use quotes for the placeholder inside the SQL; those are added by the db-api.