# python, pandas, sqlalchemy - symbols to escape in query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a query using sqlalchemy

```
df=pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM `all-data`.indicators_ft \
WHERE country= "United States" AND name="Average Hourly Earnings % m/m" ', engine)
```

However that specific query doesnt work. I isolated the problem and it is in the expression `"Average Hourly Earnings % m/m"`. I suspect it is because of the `%` or `/` symbol that would need to be escaped. But how to do that? I tried backslashes but they didnt work.

subsidiary question: I also tried `NAME LIKE "Average Hourly Earnings%"` to bypass the problem but it didnt work either - how to do a `LIKE` query in sqalchemy?

NB: I tried both those queries in mysql workbench and they did work.

Thx!

Comment: Found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037581/how-do-i-escape-from-python-mysql-query % sign is escaped by using %%

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-line string like so:

```
'''
   SELECT * FROM `all-data`.indicators_ft 
   WHERE country= "United States" AND name="Average Hourly Earnings % m/m
'''
```

Comment: Interesting but doesnt answer the question.