# Error selecting from sql table using mysql placeholders

Tags: python, mysql, sql, web-scraping, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to select some values within a table that has a column called "Name". That column contains tennis players names. I want to store some statistics for each player in python, but I am having trouble accessing the table. I keep getting a "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='Rafael Nadal'' at line 1" As you can see, mysql clearly interprets the  %s I had in place of 'Rafael Nadal' correctly, but it still brings up an error. Can anyone help me?

```
recordTuple = ('Rafael Nadal', )
mySql_insert_query = """SELECT `First_Serve(%)` FROM `serve2` WHERE Name =%s"""
cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query, recordTuple)
aI = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]/100
```

Comment: You really have a `%` in the column name? Double it to `%%`.

Comment: The %s is a placeholder. This is used in MySql python connector to represent a variable name. In this case the variable is 'Rafael Nadal'. I eventually want the user to be able select the player for themself

Comment: I know about `%s`. The problem is `First_Serve(%)`.

Comment: Try putting the column name `Name` in backticks.  [`NAME` is a reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-5-detailed-N)

Comment: Change that to `First_Serve(%%)`

Comment: @LukeWoodward It's not a reserved word, there's no `(R)` next to it.

Comment: @Barmar fair enough, it's just odd that the error is reported immediately after `Name`.

Comment: @muth: Should it not qouted: `Name ='%s'`, there is a **blank** in `'Rafael Nadal'`

Comment: @LukeWoodWard you were right, I just needed to add backticks to Name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since `%` is used to mark placeholders in the SQL, you have to double it if you want to use it literally.

```
mySql_insert_query = """SELECT `First_Serve(%%)` FROM `serve2` WHERE Name =%s"""
```

See [How do I escape % from python mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037581/how-do-i-escape-from-python-mysql-query)

Comment: Thanks but that didnt work. It returns the error "Unknown column 'First_Serve(%%)' in 'field list'". I'm pretty sure its a problem with the last part of the query because when I replace the %s with just 'Rafael Nadal' it works perfectly.

Comment: I've linked to another question like this. But maybe it's different in MySQL Connector than PyMySQL.