# Python is misunderstanding %s with date

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a query that have to get as params month.

Query below work fine and filter based on first month.

```
        """SELECT i.date, i.title, i.img, i.video FROM table as i """
                """WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(i.date, "%M %D %Y") ) = 1  """ \
                """ORDER BY (i.id) desc""")
```

When tryig to put month as parameter im receiving a error

`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

```
     """SELECT i.date, i.title, i.img, i.video FROM table as i """
                """WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(i.date, "%M %D %Y") ) = %s  """ \      
                """ORDER BY (i.id) desc""", (1))
```

Have tried with some brackets (1), (1,), [1] but wont work.

In sql the query work fine.

Comment: Can you share how you're calling it in python ?

Comment: Yes, please show a [mre] as well as the full stacktrace. There's not enough info in your post for us to be able to help you besides making a wild guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I escape % from python mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037581/how-do-i-escape-from-python-mysql-query)

Comment: Have tried but wont work:
       cursor.execute(
            """SELECT i.date, i.title, i.img, i.video FROM table as i """
            """WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(i.date, "%%Y-%%m-%%d") ) = %s  
            """ORDER BY (i.id) desc""", (1))

Comment: Pass the parameters as a tuple: `(1, )`. At the moment you are passing a single int and you should pass an iterable, a tuple with a single element needs a comma

Comment: Unrelated, but why use `"""` and then still close & reopen the quotes on each line adding a line continuation character? The idea of `"""` is to *not* have to do that.

Comment: @IainShelvington yes. thanks. %% and tuple solve issue

Comment: Is this really how one writes readable code in Python (I don't know Python)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing % with %% at date and using tuple solve the issue (1,)

```js
cursor.execute(
            """SELECT i.date, i.title, i.img, i.video FROM table as i """
            """WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(i.date, "%%M %%D %%Y") ) = %s  """ \    
            """ORDER BY (i.id) desc""", (1,))
```